# Mock time with dialogflow

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to write integration test cases for Dialogflow intent querying. Is there any way to send a request with the time mocked? I don't see anything about this in the documentation.

I can send a post request as follows:

> POST /query sample HTTPCURL curl 
> https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20150910 
> -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
> -H 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN' 
> -d '{   "contexts": [
> "shop"   ],   "lang": "en",   "query": "remind me in 3 days to call mom",   "sessionId": "12345",   "timezone": "America/New_York" }'

For example, I want to be able to say the current date is "Jun 2, 2015" so that the phrase 'in 3 days' is detected as "Jun 5, 2015" instead of 3 days from when I send the request. This way, I am able to run integration tests at anytime.

Is there a way to do this in dialogflow?